# Does $PP\subseteq BPP$ imply $PP\subseteq RP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

[Consequence of $\mathsf{NP\subseteq BPP}$ to $\mathsf{NP\subseteq ZPP}$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/45469/consequence-of-mathsfnp-subseteq-bpp-to-mathsfnp-subseteq-zpp) clarifies $NP\subseteq BPP\implies NP\subseteq RP$.

What about for $PP$? Does $PP\subseteq BPP$ imply $PP\subseteq RP$ and $PP\subseteq ZPP$?

Comment: $NP\subseteq BPP\implies NP\subseteq RP$ because BPP would provide a proof with high probably and one can use the NP algorithm to do second check. This doesn't easily go to PP